# Callback from CLLocationManager not coming if getting a Phonecall

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, cllocationmanager

I am trying to get the users location if user is getting or making a phone call. I can use the CTCallCenter for my calling events.

The if one of the states are firing i am trying to get the location...It works because i see the arrow in top right corner...

But i don´t get a callback from CLLocationmanager:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
  didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
      fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

Does somebody know´s why?

UPDATE: Just found the Solution by myself..I have to init the CLLocationManager on the main Thread...it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the Solution by myself..I have to init the CLLocationManager on the main Thread...it works now